# Default value for empty node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to transform a block of XML so that if a node (in this case "User/ShopId") is empty
it should fallback to a default value, for example "0".

How can this be accomplished with XSLT?

XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Objects Version="product-0.0.1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select='Users/User'/>
    </Objects>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="User">
    <User>
        <xsl:attribute name="Email"><xsl:value-of select="Email"/></xsl:attribute> 
        <xsl:attribute name="ShopId"><xsl:value-of select="ShopId"/></xsl:attribute> 
        <xsl:attribute name="ERPCustomer"><xsl:value-of select="ERPCustomer"/></xsl:attribute> 
        <xsl:attribute name="DisplayName"><xsl:value-of select="DisplayName"/></xsl:attribute>
    </User>
</xsl:template>
```

For example

```
<Users>
  <User>
    <Email>asdasd@gmail.com</Email>
    <ShopId>123123</ShopId>
    <ERPCustomer>100</ERPCustomer>
    <DisplayName>Username</DisplayName>
  </User>

  <User>
    <Email>asdasd2@gmail.com</Email>
    <ShopId></ShopId>
    <ERPCustomer>100</ERPCustomer>
    <DisplayName>Username</DisplayName>
  </User>
<Users>
```

would be transformed into

```
<Objects Version="product-0.0.1">
   <User Email="asdasd@gmail.com" ShopId="123123" ERPCustomer="100" DisplayName="Username"></User>
   <User Email="asdasd2@gmail.com" ShopId="0" ERPCustomer="100" DisplayName="Username"></User>
</Objects>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your code sample you could change

```
<xsl:attribute name="ShopId"><xsl:value-of select="ShopId"/></xsl:attribute>
```

to

```
<xsl:attribute name="ShopId">
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(normalize-space(ShopId))">0</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="ShopId"/></xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:attribute>
```

I would consider changing the approach to template matching and write a template

```
<xsl:template match="Users/User/ShopId[not(normalize-space())]">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">0</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

for that special case and preceed that with

```
<xsl:template match="Users/User/*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

to handle the other transformations.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll definitely do that.

Comment: You will need explicit `priority` values on those two templates as they have the same default priority.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert all child elements of "User" to attributes and on choose create their values:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Objects Version="product-0.0.1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select='Users/User'/>
    </Objects>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="User">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="User/*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=". != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```